# What is the optimal way of structuring a multiple choice preference evaluation to determine most popular photo in a set?

Tags: experiment-design

Say I have a set of photographs and I want to ascertain the most popular one based on a group of people choosing their favourite.

What is the most optimal way of structuring a survey to derive a confident estimate of most preferred photo with the smallest sample size.

For example would it be better to do...

- Show all photos and ask people to pick their favourite
- Show a subset of photos and ask people to pick favourite
- Some other structure

Does the optimal structure change if you have more options?

Comment: It would probably be best to show them in a randomized order. This way you will correct for any order effects and people rate each photo individually. Your second suggestion also sounds reasonable, but then still you need to take order effects into account and you must be able to justify the selected sets.